# how to configure SQL Server max memory usage

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 Enterprise. SQL Server 2008 always tries to eat as much as memory as it could. Any ways to configure per database or per instance or per server level max memory usage of SQL Server 2008?

thanks in advance,
George

Comment: Shouldn't this be on ServerFault?

Comment: It's hard to say with SQL Server.  Everything you can do through the management GUI, you can also execute a tsql command for... so it can kinda always be programming related ;)

Comment: Yes, this is why I ask here. Sometimes, it is both DBA and developer's boundary. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure?: [SQL SERVER 2008 - Memory Leak while storing Millions of records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276659/sql-server-2008-memory-leak-while-storing-millions-of-records/1277358#1277358)

If you really must:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options',1
reconfigure
GO
sp_configure 'max server memory',100
reconfigure
GO
```

Comment: I can only configure per server level? No instance or database level?

Comment: So, you mean connect to one SQL Server instance, and execute the commands above, will restrict current connected instance memory?

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of memory is to be used to speed up data access, not to sit around looking pretty (and empty).  SQL Server *should* use as much RAM as it can get its hand(les) on for caching in order to make the best use of available resources.

With modern server applications it's best, 99.99% of the time, to let them manage their resources as designed.

Comment: I run IIS on the same machine of SQL Server before of short of machine. I do not care speed currently, just for integration purpose. Any ideas to restrict the max memory used?