# ACT Professional for Windows-Memory leak?

Tags: sql-server-2005, windows-server-2008

I have an ACT! professional for Windows V11.1, with the latest SQL service pack (SP3) and have an apparent memory leak on the server.

After a restart the ACT! SQL instance (SQLSERVR) consumes almost all the available memory on the server, we have added more memory to the server (it is running under Hyper-V) but it continues to consume it all.

I have not been able to connect to the SQL server instance using management studio in order to limit the amount of RAM it is allocated.

Are there any potential solutions for this? or should I continue to restart the services?

Answer (score 0):

Not a memory leak, but standard behavior.

[How to configure SQL Server max memory usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475605/how-to-configure-sql-server-max-memory-usage/1475643#1475643)

[SQL SERVER 2008 - Memory Leak while storing Millions of records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276659/sql-server-2008-memory-leak-while-storing-millions-of-records/1277358#1277358)

[+ this excellent blog entry](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jonathan_kehayias/archive/2009/08/24/troubleshooting-the-sql-server-memory-leak-or-understanding-sql-server-memory-usage.aspx)

Other than that...

- x86 or x64?
- Server RAM?
- PAE/AWE/3GB switch
- DB size?
- (left field) [Trace flag 836](http://blogs.msdn.com/slavao/archive/2006/08/03/687573.aspx) (changes 32 bit memory to act like SQL 2000)

Comment: The problem is that I do not have access to the SQL instance as it came prepackaged with ACT. I did find the ACTDIAG tool on their site which will apparently allow this to be done.